# Converting bytes to string without loosing any characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I actually receive a file in bytes that is compress with two digits hexadecimals. Everytime i see \x1d, i know that the next two digits are hexadecimals

Here is an example of what we receive:

```
b"1MHG161   M01514GC    PROD  IBM418AGP001\x1d06 0478\x1d06 D89BQD0\x1d05 TFRVNT    \x1d0501B9082621421300\x1d0A 020\x1d1E $\x1d13 2TRG240
```

My problem is that we need to have a type string. When we use decode("UTF-8") we lost the \x1d before the hexadecimals digits and we are not able to know anymore where they are.

```
1MHG161   M01514GC    PROD  IBM418AGP00106 047806 D89BQD005 TFRVNT    0501B90826214213000A 0201E $13 2TRG240
```

Anyone have an idea how to transform the original file in bytes into a string without losing all these characters ?

Comment: `\x1d` is exactly *one character*, it is byte 29. There is no actual `\x1d` in the bytes object or the corresponding string. Note, if you print the `repr(s)` of your string, you'll see those bytes in the representation, those bytes get translated into a non-visible character, corresponding to the group separator escape control character. you can just use `'\x1d'` if you need to check for it in a string.

Comment: so note, if i set `data` to your original bytes object, `[i for i, c in enumerate(data.decode()) if c == '\x1d']` gives me: `[40, 48, 59, 73, 92, 99, 104]` so you didn't actually lose and data, simply put, the printed representation of that string wont have that data visible because it is invisible *by design*

Comment: thx for the answer, like you say i still can find the \x1d, it is just not visible